# How to remove symbols from a string with Python?

Tags: python, regex, string

I'm a beginner with both Python and RegEx, and I would like to know how to make a string that takes symbols and replaces them with spaces. Any help is great.

For example:

```
how much for the maple syrup? $20.99? That's ricidulous!!!
```

into:

```
how much for the maple syrup 20 99 That s ridiculous
```

Comment: My advice is to read the documentation for the [re](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html) library. It includes some pretty good examples.

Comment: Strange this is marked as a duplicate of a question asked over a year later.

Answer (score 207, accepted):

One way, using [regular expressions](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html):

```
>>> s = "how much for the maple syrup? $20.99? That's ridiculous!!!"
>>> re.sub(r'[^\w]', ' ', s)
'how much for the maple syrup   20 99  That s ridiculous   '
```

- `\w` will match alphanumeric characters and underscores
- `[^\w]` will match anything that's *not* alphanumeric or underscore

Comment: It should be noted that ^\w outside of brackets means 'match an alphanumeric character at the beginning of a line'. It's only within the brackets ( [^\w] ) that the caret symbol means 'ignore every character in here'

Comment: in stead of [^\w] you can also use \W, which is the opposite of \w.

Comment: Infect [/\W+/g] will do the magic.

Comment: will this work for a string containing 'é'  character. whether the output will retain or remove this character?

Comment: r'[^\w]' equals r'\W'

Answer (score 36):

Sometimes it takes longer to figure out the regex than to just write it out in python:

```
import string
s = "how much for the maple syrup? $20.99? That's ricidulous!!!"
for char in string.punctuation:
    s = s.replace(char, ' ')
```

If you need other characters you can change it to use a white-list or extend your black-list.

Sample white-list:

```
whitelist = string.letters + string.digits + ' '
new_s = ''
for char in s:
    if char in whitelist:
        new_s += char
    else:
        new_s += ' '
```

Sample white-list using a generator-expression:

```
whitelist = string.letters + string.digits + ' '
new_s = ''.join(c for c in s if c in whitelist)
```

Comment: I just used this whitelist method for a project I'm working on. Thanks!

Comment: +1, pythonic, love it.

Answer (score 12):

I often just open the console and look for the solution in the objects methods. Quite often it's already there:

```
>>> a = "hello ' s"
>>> dir(a)
[ (....) 'partition', 'replace' (....)]
>>> a.replace("'", " ")
'hello   s'
```

Short answer: Use `string.replace()`.

Comment: I think this answer is not complete looking at the problem