# regex in python 2.4

Tags: python, regex

I have a string in python as below:

```
"\\B1\\B1xxA1xxMdl1zzInoAEROzzMofIN"
```

I want to get the string as

```
"B1xxA1xxMdl1zzInoAEROzzMofIN"
```

I think this can be done using regex but could not achieve it yet. Please give me an idea.

Comment: Python 4?? is Python 4 here??

Comment: Sorry, I updated the question. I meant python 2.4. Sorry again.

Comment: Do you mean you want to remove all the cars between the two backslashes \?

Comment: Yes. Including the back slashes. Thanks.

Comment: Why are you using Python 2.4? This is now nearly a decade old...

Comment: Is this result of `print` or `repr` statement? In other words: is `\\` a representation of one character or two?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
st = "\B1\B1xxA1xxMdl1zzInoAEROzzMofIN"
s = re.sub(r"\\","",st)
idx = s.rindex("B1")
print s[idx:]
```

output = `'B1xxA1xxMdl1zzInoAEROzzMofIN'`

OR

```
st = "\B1\B1xxA1xxMdl1zzInoAEROzzMofIN"
idx = st.rindex("\\")
print st[idx+1:]
```

output = `'B1xxA1xxMdl1zzInoAEROzzMofIN'`

Comment: These look a bit too specific for me. What if the source is `"123\\456\\789"` - neither solution will give `"123789"` as a result.

Comment: his example was specific too, so i came with this specific solution. I thought he was facing problem with this specific string.

Comment: Thanks a lot RanRag. The second solution what I needed.

Comment: Note that this will work if you have **only one** double backslash. Yet, for this case, using list slicing is simple and efficient.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a try:

```
import re
s = "\\B1\\B1xxA1xxMdl1zzInoAEROzzMofIN"
s = re.sub(r"\\[^\\]+\\","", s)
print s
```

Tested on http://py-ide-online.appspot.com (couldn't find a way to share though)

[EDIT] For some explanation, have a look at the [Python regex documentation page](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html) and the first comment of this SO question:

[How to remove symbols from a string with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/875968/how-to-remove-symbols-from-a-string-with-python)

because using brackets `[]` can be tricky (IMHO)

In this case, `[^\\]` means *anything but two backslashes `\\`*.

So `[^\\]+` means *one or more character that matches anything but two backslashes `\\`*.

Comment: You make `\w` optional, and they may not be word chars, why not replace `\w*` with  `[^\\]+`? You'd then have a general pattern

Comment: @fge: thanks for the suggestion, I've edited my answer with your code (it took me some time to check this as I am not that familiar to Python Regex)

Answer (score 0):

If the desired section of the string is always on the RHS of a `\` char then you could use:

```
string = "\\B1\\B1xxA1xxMdl1zzInoAEROzzMofIN"
string.rpartition("\\")[2]
```

output = `'B1xxA1xxMdl1zzInoAEROzzMofIN'`