# Removing any pattern (word or regex) defined in a list from a string

Tags: python, regex, list-comprehension

I have a list

```
forbidden_patterns=['Word1','Word2','Word3','\d{4}']
```

and a string :

```
string1="This is Word1 a list thatWord2 I'd like to 2016 be readableWord3"
```

What is the way to have **string1** to have all the patterns and words defined in **forbidden_patterns** removed so it ends with :

```
clean_string="This is a list that I'd like to be readable"
```

The *\d{4}* is to remove the year pattern which in this case is *2016*

List comprehension are very welcome

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove symbols from a string with Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/875968/how-to-remove-symbols-from-a-string-with-python)

Comment: Why you have `\d{4}` ? This is a `re` pattern?

Comment: @IronFist I believe the OP wants to use regex.

Comment: yep both words and regex: edited to make this clear

Comment: @JETM : the potential duplicate is only based on re.sub where my question is about a list of patterns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you are:

```
import re

forbidden_patterns = ['Word1', 'Word2', 'Word3', '\d{4}']

string = "This is Word1 a list thatWord2 I'd like to 2016 be readableWord3"

for pattern in forbidden_patterns:
    string = ''.join(re.split(pattern, string))

print(string)
```

Essentially, this code goes through each of the patterns in `forbidden_patterns`, splits `string` using that particular pattern as a delimiter (which removes the delimiter, in this case the pattern, from the string), and joins it back together into a string for the next pattern.

**EDIT**

To get rid of the extra spaces, put the following line as the first line in the for-loop:

```
string = ''.join(re.split(r'\b{} '.format(pattern), string))
```

This line checks to see if the pattern is a whole word, and if so, removes that word and one of the spaces. Make sure that this line goes above `string = ''.join(re.split(pattern, string))`, which is "less specific" than this line.

Answer (score 2):

```py
import re

new_string = string1
for word in forbidden_words:
    new_string = re.sub(word, '', new_string)
```

Your `new_string` would be the one you want. Though, it's a bit long and removing some words leaving you with 2 spaces as `This is  a list that I'd like to  be readable`