# remove symbols from string

Tags: python, numpy

I have a file like:

```
@HWI
ABCDE
+
@HWI7
EFSA
+
???=AF
GTEY@JF
GVTAWM
```

I want to keep only the strings ( so remove everything that contains a symbol )

I tried :

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.genfromtxt(f, dtype=str)

for line in np.nditer(arr):
    if np.core.defchararray.isupper(line) and not '@?=;?+' in line:
        print line
```

but it gives :

```
@HWI
ABCDE
@HWI7
EFSA
???=AF
GTEY@JF
GVTAWM
```

and I am expecting:

```
ABCDE
EFSA
GVTAWM
```

I want to use numpy for this and not commands like regex or similar.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove symbols from a string with Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/875968/how-to-remove-symbols-from-a-string-with-python)

Comment: @AlexRosenfeld:Hello , I want to use numpy for this.

Comment: thanks for adding this to the question

Comment: Would it have lowercase letters too? Are those valid ones?

Comment: @Divakar:It may have but they are not valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my solution :

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.genfromtxt('text.txt', dtype=str)

test = np.core.defchararray.isalpha(arr) #Create a mask : True = only str and False = not only str

print arr[test] #Use the mask on arr and it will print only good values
```

Don't use `if` with numpy ! You have indexing to do that ;)

I get :

```
['ABCDE' 'EFSA' 'GVTAWM']
```

Answer (score 0):

W/ numpy:

There is an isalpha() and isnumeric() function to numpy as well. They can be read about [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.char.html).

Without numpy, you could try this regex:

`re.sub(r'[^\w]', ' ', s)`

where `s` is your string and `[^\w]` will match anything that's not alphanumeric or underscore

An example on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/875968/how-to-remove-symbols-from-a-string-with-python)

Comment: I am using numpy.I don't want to use regex

Comment: Alright, you should specify the requirements in the question.