# Renaming files in Windows

Tags: python, windows, powershell

I have a bunch of files in Windows that have prefix and a suffix that needs to be removed.

For example

```
[video] Home Video - 014 Sunday Night[480p] [x265] [robert].mkv
[video] Home Video - 015 Monday Night[480p] [x265] [robert].mkv
[video] Home Video - 016 Tuesday Night[480p] [x265] [robert].mkv
```

I want to rename these files so it will say

```
014 Sunday Night
015 Monday Night
016 Tuesday Night
```

I don't mind using PowerShell, Python, Bat or anything else Windows has to offer.
I'd rather not download a 3rd party tool but would consider it if it's needed

Comment: Are they folders or files?

Comment: it's for files only!

Comment: What are the file extensions?

Comment: all files are MKV. They have square brackets. I've tried Rename-Item but it says file doesn't exist when it does

Comment: You could right-click > rename. Kidding! :) You could try FileBot but I think they are now paid. There must be a free alternatve somewhere. EDIT: I just realise they must be home-made... oops.

Answer (score 1):

you can read the files with "os" in python and replace the name with a regular expresion:

Read files: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_rename.htm

Rename files with python: [Rename multiple files in a directory in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2759067/rename-multiple-files-in-a-directory-in-python)

Use regex to delete text : [How to remove symbols from a string with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/875968/how-to-remove-symbols-from-a-string-with-python)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a single PowerShell cmdlet:

```
Get-ChildItem *.mkv | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.name -Replace '.*?(\d{3}.*?)\[.*?\.','$1.'}
```

Comment: If you'd like to check the output before going through with this add -WhatIf at the end of the Rename-Item cmdlet: `Get-ChildItem *.mkv | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.name -Replace '.*?(\d{3} Clip \d).*?\.','$1.'} -WhatIf`

Comment: Thanks but the Clip 1, Clip 2 were the names of the actual track. It's literally not called Clip X. I need to remove the square brackets and extra white spaces before and after the 00N Clip 1

Comment: @softwareisfun Can you add some more examples to your question? It's still pretty unclear right now, because `Folder Name - ` doesn't look like whitespace to me.

Comment: @softwareisfun Updated my regex.

Comment: Do i need to save the script in the same directory as the files?

Comment: @softwareisfun You can save it if you like, but yes, it does have to be in the same directory.