# Regex: remove 's from a string?

Tags: python, regex

string input: `Python's Programming: is very easy to learn`

expected output: `Python Programming: is very easy to learn`

Here is what I have so far which isn't working:

```
import re
mystr = "Python's Programming: is very easy to learn"
reg = r'\w+'
print(re.findall(reg, mystr))
```

How do I remove the `'s` from `python's`?

Comment: (From a deleted answer) See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/875978/11097997

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove specific characters from a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3939361/remove-specific-characters-from-a-string-in-python)

Comment: [Remove specific characters from a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3939361/remove-specific-characters-from-a-string-in-python) has nothing to do with the current question.

Answer (score 2):

You extract all matches of one or more alphanumeric characters.

Use

```
\b's\b
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/3mvtJB/1).

**Explanation**:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  's                       '\'s'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
```

[Python code](https://tio.run/##Hcw7CsMwEAXA3qd4qJENJo27QO7gA7iRYHEE1oe3m4BOL4PrgWndvrVsY6TcKg2UKXc14gO3P@YVO@vJkHMq5xtJ8Rd2SNAOq7gksLipMRWbKS/9xZnuiF6P6FZ4v@IZl2WMGw):

```py
import re
mystr = "Python's Programming: is very easy to learn"
print(re.sub(r"\b's\b", '', mystr))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are two options. The first uses regex, and the second uses the string `replace` method.

```
import re
mystr = "Python's Programming: is very easy to learn"
reg = r"'s"
print(re.sub(reg, '', mystr))
   # prints: Python Programming: is very easy to learn
print(mystr.replace("'s",''))
   # prints: Python Programming: is very easy to learn
```

Comment: Replacing `'s`  without checking word boundaries can cause side effects. Try with `'such an awesome language'` string.

Comment: I'm actually not sure what you say is true. Seems to work fine without word boundaries on your string. Unless you mean ```mystr = "'such an awesome language'"```. But this seems highly unlikely

Comment: I have removed the word boundaries. I don't think they are necessary in this case.

Comment: And didn't intend to "copy" your answer. I just saw a comment on my answer and addressed it. Hadn't looked at your answer.